# Unique PHP and HTACCESS domain forwarding issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a site hosted at Network Solutions, along with two domains. "OldDomain" used to point to hosting account, but now "NewDomain" points to host.

PROBLEM: Redirecting "OldDomain" doesn't work without creating redirect loops.

I've tried the following:

1) Redirecting OldDomain (with/out "www"), plus redirect non-www for NewDomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

2) Redirect using PHP header:

```
$dom = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if(strripos($dom, 'olddomain.com') >= 0) {
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.newdomain.com/");
}
```

Option #1 doesn't do anything. Option #2 puts me in a redirect loop even with the first two `RewriteCond` rules commented out.

I've done many .htaccess redirects before, but this one is giving me a headache as to why it's not acting right. Is this just a Network Solutions issue? I've never had problems with any other hosts. By the way, NS support tells me I have to pay to forward OldDomain to NewDomain because it's currently not pointing to a hosting package. If that's the case, why can't I point both domains to the same hosting package and at least use the PHP redirect in the header of the index page??

THANKS for any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 doesn't do anything because you have this logic in your conditions

- Host is `www.olddomain.com`
- **OR** host is `olddomain.com`
- **AND** host is `newdomain.com`

Obviously, the host can't both be `newdomain.com` and either one of the old domains. Try adding an additional `[OR]` to that and some `[NC]`, too:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Option 2, you have this to see if the host contains `olddomain.com`:

```
if(strripos($dom, 'olddomain.com') >= 0) {
```

Problem here is `strripos()` returns **FALSE** (which is also a 0) if string isn't found, which means if `$dom` was `www.newdomain.com`, it would return **FALSE**, or `0`, and the `>= 0` would be true, thus redirecting again. You need to do something like this:

```
if(strlen(strstr($dom, 'olddomain.com')) > 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon... I'll give those a try. Makes sense. ... Do you think it really matters which I use? I'm guessing for simplicity sake it's best to put everything in the htaccess, unless something is getting missed by the server when someone uses "olddomain.com"? That's the whole reason I attempted the PHP solution to begin with, since I was wondering/worried that there are 2 domains pointing to the same hosting account (i.e. same IP address).

Comment: @gtr1971 I don't know how you have your PHP script set up (I assume in an include somewhere?), but I'd guess the mod_rewrite rules are probably simpler.

Comment: I was finally able to test out your solution and it worked. As you mentioned, I was missing the 2nd "OR" statement. Once I put that in, everything worked as intended. THANKS!